# Programming Pearls: Column 9.3 Binary Search - range initialization

Tags: algorithm, binary-search, programming-pearls

In Section 9.3 Job Bentley presents a modified binary search..

a brief snip of the typical implementation and the better approach shown in 9.3

```
if (arr[mid] < key) low = mid+1
else if (arr[mid] > key) high = mid-1
else return mid;
```

modified/efficient comparison with a different invariant..

```
if (arr[mid] < key) low = m;
else high = m;
```

And outside the loop there is a check if the key at the index 'high'. In the modified binary search the left index 'low' starts at -1 (instead of 0) and 'high' index starts at n (instead of n-1).. and the loop runs

```
while (low + 1 != high)
```

This modified search seems to work even if I set low = 0 and high = n-1.

But I would rather not second guess Job Bentley in his code. So why is he setting low to -1 and high to n ? Is there any corner case where only this will work ?

Comment: An array of 0 or 1 element

Comment: Thanks. If you make it an answer I will accept that.

Comment: it is done. I only addressed the empty array case. Feel free to explore the one element case following my approach.

Comment: You can show the entire optimized binary search code to make the question more clear.@Manohar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an array that is empty (`n == 0`), then a check of `while(low + 1 != high`) will only correctly terminate if `low` begins at `-1` and `high` at `0`.

`while((-1 + 1) != 0) //true`

If `low` began at `0` instead,  or `high` began at `-1` (or both),  then the loop will clearly perform at least one check:

- `while((0 + 1) != 0) // false`
- `while((-1 + 1) != -1) // false`
- `while((0 + 1) != -1) // false`

That one check on an empty array will likely access an out of bounds index, which invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: The other edge case is with a 1-element array. If `low` was initialized to 0 and `high` to `n-1 = 0`, it would loop forever.